# why don't I need catch the SQLExecption when I use db.exec() on android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqlexception

Why don't I need `catch` the `SQLExecption` when I use `db.exec()` on android?

The db is a `SQLiteDatabase` object.

when I write the code following, Eclipse don't remind me to catch the `SQLException` and the code can run normally.However,the method should throw a `SQLException` according to document provided by eclipse.

I think the programmer should catch every `exception` or add throws statement when creating a method in java.

The following is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("keys.db",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    String sql="CREATE TABLE `mykey` (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            "public_key VARCHAR, private_key VARCHAR)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    db.close();
}
```

thanks.

Comment: time to look at checked/unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/SQLException.html): `SQLException` extends `RuntimeException` and you don't need a `throws` clause for these.

EDIT: Please note that this applies to Android only. In Java SE, `SQLException` does not derive from `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Thanks.I think you are right.Because when I test this in Java SE.Eclipse reports a error.So this confuse me.

Answer (score 3):

If a method doesn't throw an exception, or throws a RuntimeException, you don't have to catch it.

Since the method throws a RuntimeException, you're not required to catch it (just like a NullPointerException or an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception).

However, the exception will crash your program. You still *can* catch the exception, just use a try catch.

Comment: Yep. SQLException extends RuntimeException